# JSON.parse не сохраняет порядок

Tags: javascript, json

Есть json объект вида

```
object {viewTable: "[{"Name":"1","id":"25","Max":"25"}]", totalItems: 6}
```

Нужно из него взять `viewTable` и тоже перевести в Json.
Для этого я использовал 
`tableResult = JSON.parse(object);`

Проблема в том что порядок после этого у объекта другой не такой как изначально а по порядку ключа.

```
[{"id":"25","Max":"25","Name":"1"}]
```

А мне нужен исходный порядок `[{"Name":"1","id":"25","Max":"25"}]`. Можно ли это как-то исправить?

Система по себе очень большая и переделывать с большими изменениями смысла нет ,так как все завязано. так как много действий происходит в c# для формирования подобного объекта 
`object {viewTable: "[{"Name":"1","id":"25","Max":"25"}]", totalItems: 6}`
после получения данного объекта нужно чтобы был тот же порядок. Так в c# происходят разные сортировки и прочее,прежде чем сформировать объект такой.

вывод делал из javascript с помощью console.log

Comment: почему вы думаете, что порядок изменился? как проверяли? почему вы думаете, что вам нужен какой-то конкретный порядок?

Comment: Еще местами непонятна форулировка вопроса. У вас `object.viewTable` - это строка, в ней сидит массив в JSON-формате. Значит вам этот массив нужно перевести не __в__ JSON, а __из__ JSON

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос, в какой среде вы это проверяли

Comment: эм, а зачем сохранять порядок, когда это объект, а к объекту обращаются по его свойствам?

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя, JavaScript не гарантирует порядок полей в объектах.

Из спецификации ECMAScript 3

> #### 4.3.3 Object
>
> An object is a member of the type Object. **It is an unordered collection of properties** each of which contains a primitive value, object, or function. A function stored in a property of an object is called a method.

Из более свежей ECMAScript 6

> #### 9.1.11 [[Enumerate]] ()
>
> When the [[Enumerate]] internal method of O is called the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Return an Iterator object (25.1.1.2) whose next method iterates over all the String-valued keys of enumerable properties of O. The Iterator object must inherit from %IteratorPrototype% (25.1.2). **The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties is not specified** but must conform to the rules specified below.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Отфильтровал с помощью отдельного цикла.